# Update page url on click without reload

Tags: ajax

I'm curious what is the technology behind this type of updating page url without refresh.

For example this website: stonestyle.co.th

When I click on any of the navigaion items it loads a new page but without refresh and very slick.

Is it Ajax or html history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a js router which will use the browser history to manipulate the url and change one page to another, the easiest way to implement this, is to use a frontend framework like [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/), [angular](https://angular.io/).

but you can do it yourself with Ajax and this library https://github.com/krasimir/navigo
[enter link description here](https://vuejs.org/)

Comment: Yes you're right. I checked vue js router and I think that it will to the job :)

Comment: so can you please mark this answer as the right answer